# Multi-lingual for Product Description

Tags: virtocommerce

In a Product page of the front-end Demo Store, under the **Description** and **Additional Information** tabs are still in English even if I have changed the site language to Japanese. The same goes to the name of the Categories (Audio & MP3, Computers & Tablets, Cameras, etc).

Can I provide my own translation of Japanese for these areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translating **Additional Information**:

1. Open catalog and add Japanese language to it ([catalog guide](http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc1userguide/Creating%2C+editing+and+deleting+a+Catalog));
2. Open concrete product, navigate to Properties, change displayed properties language to
   Japanese (by clicking language filter in top left corner);
3. Fill in the properties and save;
4. In order to see the changes in website, rebuild the search index ([settings guide](http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc1userguide/Search+Settings)).

The **Description** (Editorial Review) doesn't support localization at the moment. There are several workarounds but they all include programming.

Comment: I managed to make localization works for Products. What about Category display name?

Comment: The value for Category name is taken from **Title** property in Category. In case properties list is empty, make sure to select "Category type" in Summary tab. If only Title property is missing, create it in the catalog and add it to appropriate Property Set.

Comment: I saw the **Title** property, however I couldn't see any options to set it in different languages. There isn't any "language filter" like in the Product property.

Comment: Close all category editing dialogs, select Refresh in catalogs tree context menu and try opening category again. "Language filter" should be there.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.
Last question, you said there are several workarounds in providing localization to Editorial Review, do you have any pointers on where to start? I don't mind some programming.

Comment: You can use source field and format it in this way "group_lang", so for example english you will have "fullreview_en", for japanese "fullreview_jp". And then filter them based on that in frontend. We'll be adding language property to review in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can provide your own content. Some of the text simply wasn't translated to the Japanese. You can translate everything from category names to labels using Commerce Manager console. For categories, simply go to the category edit page and set a translating for display name property to Japanese.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to VirtoCommerce. How exactly do I provide a translation for **Description** and **Additional Information** of a particular product? Using Commerce Manager, from the Main Menu -> Products -> <Double click on a product> -> Editorial Reviews, I can see an entry here which is the Description in English. How do I proceed from here?

How do I also create/edit Categories? From the Main Menu I can only see Products and Catalogs but no Categories.